# Failing to Create New File (Python)

Tags: python

I created a small function to log any errors to a new file, however I'm getting errors when I shouldn't. I've searched around and all the answers to this question use the same method I am using now, however I'm getting errors.

```
with open(f'Z:/FTP/errors/error-{get_timestamp(False)}.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(str(e))
```

The above is my code and below is the error I am receiving (truncated):

```
  File "Main.py", line 42, in log_error
    with open(f'Z:/FTP/errors/error-{get_timestamp(False)}.txt', 'w+') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Z:/FTP/errors/error-2017-10-14T19:08:07.577362.txt'
```

What is going wrong? Am I too blind to see a mistake I've made?

Comment: Does the path exist? IIRC it will only try to create the file if it doesn't exist, not the directories.

Comment: Problem is most likely that Windows does not allow colons in a file or directory name. Your timestamp has colons.

Comment: Ahh hell... Thanks @Mark. I always forget that stupid rule.

Answer (score 0):

You need create 'errors' folder before you write to file:

```
import os
os.makedirs(f'Z:/FTP/errors')
```

Comment: The directory exists. Should have included it in the code, but I create the directory if it doesn't exist (also, I can see the directory in my file explorer).

Answer (score -1):

Check that you have permissions to write to the folder.